# Git - Ignoring Last Changes I Made In My Local

Tags: php, git, version-control, terminal

I have made some changes in a file and I broke it at some point. I have all the version control in bitbucket.

When I try: `git status`, I get  `modified:resources/views/app.blade.php` however I don't want to commit it, instead I wanna bring back the working version. I didn't push the broken version, so the last one on git is the working version.

What is the command necessary for me to ignoring all the last changes I have made on my local?

Will `git pull origin working branch` work? I want to ignore all the latest changes that I made on my local for only that single file (`app.blade.php`) that I didn't push yet, and pull the latest working version from git.

Something like `git ignore last changes that I made on app.blade.php & pull the working version of app.blade.php` *the latest pushed version on git is the working one, i didn't push broken one*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout -- .
```

will undo all non-committed local changes

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

will undo all non-committed local changes to file